# Connection string from Web.Config not read by ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-config, configurationmanager

I have a connection string in my Web.Config file:

```xml
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Test" connectionString="MyConnString"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And am trying to access it in my code like this:

```cs
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
```

Why am I receiving this error?

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object.

`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"]` is NULL but I can't figure out why.

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1

I installed `System.Configuration.Configuration` version 6.0.0 using NuGet.

I have the correct using statement at the top of my code file: `using System.Configuration;`

Comment: You should check the docs on ASP.NET Core configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0. It has changed quite a bit from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ASP.NET Core no longer uses the `Global.asax` and `web.config` files that
> previous versions of ASP.NET utilized.
>
> The `web.config` file has also been replaced in ASP.NET Core.
> Configuration itself can now be configured, as part of the application
> startup procedure described in `Startup.cs`. Configuration can still
> utilize XML files, but typically ASP.NET Core projects will place
> configuration values in a JSON-formatted file, such as
> `appsettings.json`.

Read the following article: [Migrate configuration to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

So, you can rename the `web.config` to `app.config`.

But better solution is to update application to use JSON-formatted file, such as `appsettings.json`. For more information read the following article: [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)